# Transactions not being mined on Quorum QBFT Chain

Tags: mining, private-blockchain, quorum, mining-pools, qbft

I am deploying the smart contract on Quorum QBFT Chain using Nethereum with running 5 Nodes,but transaction being not mined yet stucking in mining.

Please check and help me on it ...

I am adding my genesis file also...[image: Open Genesis file]

[image: seconf part of Genesis file]

Here is my txpool page which is indicating transaction pending [image: open txpool pic]

Kindly please check it all and give yours valuable solutions...

I am expecting transaction should be mined